# Кнопка и надпись находится поверх текста

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, я сделал кнопку DOWNLOAD зеленого цвета которая стоит по центру и надпись coming soon.... под ней, кнопку я выравнял с помощью flex, но после добавления еще одного тега p (параграфа) текст появился под кнопкой и словом, позиционирование кнопки, слова и параграфов relative, как это исправить? И еще при добавлении тега br кнопка с текстом отодвигаются вниз. Не ругайте сильно если допустил очень глупую ошибку, я новичок в сфере веб-программирования.

Comment: и еще не работает ссылка-якорь на 3-й параграф, хотя указано также как и в остальных ссылках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Она стоит после параграфа? Если нет - поставь после

Comment: спасибо, помогло.